# What are some of the best Physics resources online?

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

Are there any sites similar to (in terms of function and quality) Paul's Online Math Notes, 17Calculus.com, or PatrickJMT.com, for Physics (besides Khan Academy)?

I've googled this, but the sites I've found were described as high-school level, and I'm not sure if these would be adequate/appropriate for getting help for a college physics course.

I'm aware of and a frequent user of Khan Academy, but I'm hoping to find recommendations for additional resources.

Edit: I can see how it might seem this question duplicates [Learning physics online](/questions/679/learning-physics-online), but it is different. Here's why:

I'm not seeking to learn physics online—I'm a college student who just began Physics I, and I'm looking for physics resources, similar to *supplemental* resources like Paul's Online Math Notes or 17calculus.com you might visit if you were studying calculus.

I've googled this before asking my question, naturally, but the resources I found were either geared towards high-school students, or they were in formats, such as forums, that aren't conducive to systematic learning/studying. I also explored this site looking for similar questions that might have the answers I'm seeking, but I did not find any that were directly in line with the sort of well-organized, systematic approach that makes it easy to find and follow information pertinent to that which you're currently studying. PatrickJMT.com is another example of the sort of site I had in mind; only the publisher focuses primarily on calculus and only touches briefly on physics problems.

If more advanced users community say the high-school resources are adequate for helping a student in a college Physics I course, that'd be great!

Otherwise, I was merely hoping for some recommendations for well-organized resources designed and/or appropriate for supplementing a conventional course, similar to the abundant resources you'd find for mathematics.

If you'd reopen my question, it would benefit not only me, but also huge numbers of other people who are or will be studying physics. Thanks!

Comment: Physics Forums.

Comment: @ChesterMiller: Eh, that's not really a learning resource like Kahn academy, is it?

Comment: try this app: https://towardbrightspark.com. It is free and fun.